# JS regex match a word option with no backref

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have:

```
/(private|public|protected)\s+function\s+(\w+)\((.*)\)\s+{/gi
```

To match the beginning of a function declaration. I don't want to use `(private|public|protected)` because the `(` and `)` make for a backreference, but I can't use `[` and `]` because they don't match the full words.

Basically, I only want the function name as `$1` and arguments as `$2`.

Thanks all.

** edit **

Per the answer, I used `?:`

eg. `/(?:private|public|protected)\s+function\s+(\w+)\((.*)\)\s+{/`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: This seems to match the function name. `\((.*)\)` matches the arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a non-capturing group:

```
(?: ... )
```

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> `(?:x)`    Matches `'x'` but does not remember the match. These are called non-capturing parentheses. The matched substring can not be recalled from the resulting array's elements `[1], ..., [n]`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'm not sure if I understand. If you omit the brackets, then e.g. `public function foo() {}` would only match `public` and not the rest of the string...

Comment: I'm sure you're right, please disregard. I've just been told off for using `(?:...)` unnecessarily with alternations.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'd seen `?:` before in my prior google searches, but didn't know that it would expunge a match. Thanks!